# C offset is 2 with treesit

Tags: indentation, c, tree-sitter

I recently started using `treesit` and I'm noticing with C files, my auto-indent is 2 spaces. How can I fix this to make it 4 spaces again? I've tried `c-basic-offset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably in `c-ts-mode`, so the correct variable is `c-ts-mode-indent-offset`. `c-basic-offset` is only for buffers that are in `c-mode`.

Comment: Is there a way to make it guess the offset of the buffer so it doesn't have to reformat?

Comment: Not that I know of. You would probably have to write that yourself if you really want it. It is probably better to use directory–local variables.

Comment: How do you mean directory local?

Comment: I mean that you can give a variable like `c-ts-mode-indent-offset` a different value for files in different directories. Search for it, it’s in the Emacs manual (`C-h i`).